# Serverless AWS container lambda (node) not being updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

So, first go at AWS LAmbda Containers (need to deploy a "big-ish" Lambda) and we use Serverless framework for all other Lambdas and I tried it for the container as well.

It all went fine and the Lambda was created with all the expected parameters following this blog/guide: https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda

Of course I had messed up the code and forgotten a module so teh Lambda didn't run in AWS.

I added the module and did a re-deploy (`sls deploy`) from my laptop and it writes out everything as "success" like in half a second so it is clear it is not deploying anything (I am using the `--force` flag as well but no difference.

The only way to get it updated seems to be to alter some code and save it and Serverless will "detect" a change and redeploy (for real).
This will cause a problem in our DevOps deploy pipeline so any way of getting it redeploying through a parameter/command?

[image]

Comment: As a workaround until you figure out how to solve this with `serverless`, you can add this to your CI/CD pipeline (using the AWS CLI): `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name <image-name> --image-uri <image-uri>`. This will reload the Docker image from ECR (which should be done after every deployment of the image).

Comment: Thanks @Jens, we might have to consider something like that...

Comment: hi what versión of sls use ?